# Button styling in flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

[Executed program picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWMeA.png) I need help. I want to make the button click circular instead of rectangular.
This is the flutter dart code that I've provided, I want to know what attribute I should change or insert for making my question possible.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Ask me anything',
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Ask me anything'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[700],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
      body: MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int ballNumber = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
        child: Expanded(
      child: TextButton(
        style: ButtonStyle(enableFeedback: true,shape: ),
        onPressed: () => setState(() {
          ballNumber = Random().nextInt(5) + 1;
        }),
        child: Image.asset(
          'images/ball$ballNumber.png',
          width: 400,
          // height: 200,
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either change button style, or just wrap the image with `GestureDetector`.

---

### Round Button

[image: Round button]

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    shape: const CircleBorder(),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const FittedBox(
    child: Text('Round Button'),
  ),
),
```

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<CircleBorder>(
      const CircleBorder(),
    ),
    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
      const EdgeInsets.all(50),
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const FittedBox(
    child: Text('Round Button'),
  ),
),
```

---

### GestureDetector

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    setState(() {
      ballNumber = Random().nextInt(5) + 1;
    });
  },
  child: Image.asset('images/ball$ballNumber.png'),
),
```